Launching Android Emulator Pixel 5 API 34 reboots Windows
For my .NET MAUI App on Android, I use the Android Emulator Pixel 5 API 34 with the following settings below. Unfortunately, this very often leads to a reboot of Windows when the Emulator is launched. It is not like everytime, but at least that often that I wanted to ask what could be the reason and what I should do to prevent that?


Have you tried collecting information from logs, as for what reason the reboot happens?

try to lower hw.ramsize, it could be that you don't have enough actual ram

@H.A.H. - Analyzing the Windows-Event-Logs is difficult for me here, and I could not identify the right log entry to one of the crashes. I really forgot to look at them when I had the crashes, this could have helped. I will do it next time I get a reboot

@o_w - That's a good hint and I will try that to see if it changes anything. My total memory is really used up to 87% when the emulator is started. I also think about extending my memory (RAM) here. But, to be honest, I would not expect a Windows reboot when running out of memory. At least they should give a hint that there is not enough memory available to run the emulator successfully

Could this also have something to do with the HAXM-Driver?

@OXO Side question - do you have Hyper-V turned on?

At least in the Windows Optional Features (Win + R, optionalfeatures) "Hyper-V" is not activated. Nevertheless, in Windows Systeminformation (Win + R, msinfo32), I see "Hyper-V - VM-Monitoring extension: yes", "Hyper-V - SLAT-Extension (Second Level Address Translation): yes",  "Hyper-V - SLAT-Extension (Second Level Address Translation): yes", "Hyper-V - Virtualization Firmware activated: yes" and "Hyper-V - Data execution prevention: yes"

Now, I got a crash again, but it is really hard to find information about that crash. When I look into the Windows Event Log, I can see an Error in red "Severe hardware error. A log entry with a description of the condition is located in the data area of this event." and one "Critical" in Red: "The system was restarted without being properly shut down first. This error can occur if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.", but not really good invormation what it was. Is there anything, I can provide for you and look somewhere else?
